# Two columns combined "as" one in SQL

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have three columns

```
Field A = A,B,C 
Field B = D,E,F  
Field C = G,H,I
```

How can I combine them into one single row WITHOUT using "union all"?

Like this:

```
select Field A as 1 from TableZ 
union all 
select Field B as 1 from TableZ
union all 
select Field C as 1 from TableZ
```

The reason I do not want to use a union is because the real query I am making is big, so I don't want to repeat the code 3 times. Important to say is that I do not wish to concat the three columns, I just want to add them in single row.

Comment: You say _"How can I combine them into one single row"_, but your example query doesn't do that, it transposes each column to its own row. Please provide a the expected results for your query. If you want all fields in the same row, then using `select "Field A", "Field B", "Field C" from TableZ` puts them in a single row, but I don't think that is what you want (as you seem to want to transpose the columns to their own row).

Comment: Usually such kind of questions happen when database is designed in a way that doesn't suit application purpose. Is it possible to redesign it keeping all these values already in single column? Or may be redesign the application to handle values in several columns instead of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat your query - use [Common Table Expressions](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html), commonly known as CTE.

Here is an example:

```sql
WITH t1 as (
  -- My very long ang complicated query
  SELECT my_fields
  FROM TableZ 
)
select FieldA as f1 from t1 
union all 
select FieldB as f1 from t1 
union all 
select FieldC as f1 from t1
```

Comment: simple and clean! greate thanks..powerful common table expressions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to transpose those columns instead of *"combine them into one single row"* (see also my comment), I offer an alternative to the solution of markalex:

```sql
with original_query as (
  SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC
  FROM TableZ 
),
distribute (discriminator) as (
  select 1 from rdb$database
  union all select 2 from rdb$database
  union all select 3 from rdb$database
)
select 
  case discriminator 
    when 1 then FieldA
    when 2 then FieldB
    when 3 then FieldC
  end as "1"
from original_query
cross join distribute
```

Here the helper CTE `distribute` is cross-joined with your original query, and you then use the values of `distribute.discriminator` to decide which column to show.

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/A6asW5iZ